# How to cap this water pipe so it is flushed with the concrete?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe

The builder left this water pipe sticking out of the ground.  How to cap it off so it is flush with the concrete?  Otherwise the top off cap will stick out and create a tripping hazard or the plumber will need to break the concrete around the pipe.

Please help with any advice!

[image]

Comment: What is if for?  Did the plans change during building?  Is this inside or outside?  It appears to be outdoors due to the rain downspout.  When someone stubs a pipe up like this they have a plan, the question is what changed or wasn’t communicated.  There is more to this story than “shoddy work”.   To fix to flush part of the concrete will have to be chipped away, there is no other way to make it flush.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a cleanout to me. I would cut that thing as close to the concrete as you can with a hacksaw. Then take a die grinder (Dremel Tool) and cut it down to flush from inside the pipe. Then get a [**Flush Cleanout Repair Plug**](https://ipscorp.com/plumbing/testtite/mechanicalplugs/flushclean) and secure it with the tool that comes with it. You don't need any glue or any threadings and it will hold up to 50' of back pressure. They are available in several different sizes to fit your needs.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  DR Horton came out and cut the pipe!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not a floor drain with a test cap? Cut it off with a reciprocating saw and deburr. Pour a bunch of water into the pipe. If it holds water then it's trapped and is a floor drain. If it doesn't, plug it with a rubber compression cleanout plug.